Unable to create backup with mariabackup: try increasing innodb_log_file_size
I am running a huge database of about 3TB of data with MariaDB 10.11.9 on a mirrored ZFS vdev with SSDs.
Whenever I try to use Mariabackup with this database, it fails near the end with a message like:
`mariabackup --target-dir=/mnt/ --slave-info --backup
...
[00] FATAL ERROR: [timestamp] Was only able to copy log from 148582842890306 to 148638022288286, not 148676138598341; try increasing innodb_log_file_size`

The innodb_log_file_size is 32GB; I even tried 128GB, but it does not fix the problem.
Some time after Mariabackup starts, it repeatedly complains until the end with the same message:
Retrying read of log at LSN=148638022288286
The backuptarget has plenty of space free.
I increased innodb_log_file_size and tried this on three different slave-servers (all handle about 1TB to 3TB data) with the very same result. After a few hours of mariabackup-runtime, the backup fails with this error message.
The expectation is, that the backup finishes successfully. In another question the author "fixed" it with a restart of mariadb, but does not help in my case. Any idea what is going wrong here?

MDEV-34062 might soon allow mariadb-backup --backup to access the server’s ib_logfile0 via memory mapped I/O. That should avoid some costly re-parsing of log snippets.

Another temporary workaround I found is to use:
mariabackup --backup \
  --slave-info \
  --safe-slave-backup \
  --safe-slave-backup-timeout=300

This seems to help.
Keep in mind that the "--safe-slave-backup" option will pause replication until the backup has completed.

From the code, there's a fixed 5 second window to keep up.
If for any reason this fails, its an immediate failure.
There's scope to improve implementation. Please raise a bug report. As a workaround once a bug report is raised I'll provide temporary packages with this 5 second hard coded raised to enable you to have a working backup in the mean time.
Also MDEV-23947 feature should improve the performance of the backup once implemented.
